# Redis ASP.NET SessionState

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redis, session-state

I am starting to play around with Redis (**Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider**) I want to use it as a SessionState Server, here is my use case: Server1 runs application1 (ASP MVC) that reads/writes a kv to/from Session(HttpContext), application is moved to Server2 and need to gets the same kv from Session.
using default configuration of Redis server it seems that keys are always attached to SessionId (*ApplicationName_SessionId_Data*) hence kv are different for each Session.
Is there a specific configuration from Redis that I misses or is this normal behaviour?

Thanks.